# How to add additional parameters to every request in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to add an optional referral parameter to every URL of my node.js app. I could do the following, but I am thinking about a more efficient/elegant way of achieving this, so my code won't end being too long unnecessarily:

```
app.get('/product/:example/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('product.ejs', { product : product[req.param('example')] });
});

app.get('/product/:example/referrer/:user/', function (req, res) {
  // do referral stuff
  res.render('product.ejs', { product : product[req.param('example')] });
});
```

I am thinking about something like this (which obviously doesn't work):

```
app.get('/product/:example/',  function (req, res) { ... });
app.get('/category/:example/', function (req, res) { ... });
// set up all GET requests ...

app.get('/*/referrer/:user/', function (req, res, next) {
  // do referral stuff
  req.next();
});
```

Thanks!

Jorge

EDIT: Thank you for your response, mvuajua. I played around with it and I figured out the following. I hope this will help someone:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.url.search('/referrer/') > -1) {
    res.redirect(req.url.substring(0, req.url.search('/referrer')));
    var referrer = req.url.substring(req.url.search('/referrer/')+10,req.url.length);
    // do stuff with referrer;
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a middleware, something like

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    // do stuff here
    next();
});
```

You can also scope it to specific routes, with regular expressions if needed (not sure if that one will work, play around with it a bit until it fits your needs):

```
app.use(/(.*)\/referrer\/(.*)/, function(req, res, next) {
    // do stuff here
    next();
});
```

You still need to account for the parameter in your routes though (or they won't match), or do a redirect in the middleware to the url without the referrer part.